# Is there a way to convert byte array to ADODB.Stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, adodb

I am using an old Resume parser system that uses a method `ProcessStream(ref Stream oStream)` where the Stream is of type `ADODB.Stream`. i have a byte array that I want to convert to this stream but I am unable to.
I tried converting the byte array to `IO Stream` and then Casting it to ADODB.Stream but that also doesn't work.

[image: This is the documentation for the method i want to call]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for you.

**Method 1 loads the data in to the `ADODB.Stream` from a file.**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    String someString = "Sample string";
    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someString);

    File.WriteAllBytes("D:\\test.txt", bytes);

    ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.Stream();
    stream.Open();
    stream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary;
    stream.LoadFromFile("D:\\test.txt");

    Byte[] readData = stream.Read(someString.Length);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(bytes, readData);
}
```

**Method 2 loads the data in to the `ADODB.Stream` from an in-memory byte array.**

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    String someString = "Sample string";
    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someString);

    ADODB.Stream stream = new ADODB.Stream();
    stream.Open();
    stream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary;
    stream.Write(bytes);

    stream.Position = 0;

    Byte[] readData = stream.Read(someString.Length);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(bytes, readData);
}
```

At the end of each method I inspected the `readData` variables and it held the same data as the original 'bytes' Byte Array.

Comment: Thank you so much :) . I was able to do it with the second method.